# How to Read TagHelper property text value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, propertyinfo

i want to get string text of assigned property name?
for example:
I have a TagHelper:

```
public class CustomControl: TagHelper
{
[HtmlAttributeName("Items")]
public IEnumerable<object> DataItems { get; set; }

public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
   string stringText=datatitems.GetType()??? //it should result "listDataBC"
}
```

then used on any page :

```
<customcontrol Items="listDataBC"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ModelExpression` as parameter and use "@listDataBC" to get the name and values.
CustomControl.cs

```
    public class CustomControl : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("Items")]
        public ModelExpression expression { get; set; }

        public async override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
        
            var name = expression.Name;
            var value = expression.Model; 
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    var listDataBC = new List<object>()
    {
        new {Name="tom"},
        new {Name="kite"}
    };
}
<custom-control Items="@listDataBC"></custom-control>
```

Test result
[image]